# How to Add Related Entities to EF Core Razor Page Create Entity Form

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have the following entities:

```
 public class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ItemVersion> ItemVersion { get; set; }
    }

 public class ItemVersion
    {
        public int ItemVersionId { get; set; }
        public string ItemColor { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public <Item> Item { get; set; }
    }
```

I have scaffolded my Item entity to create the CRUD pages.  How do I get the create and update models to be bound to not just the Item, but also the ItemVersion entity so that the Edit and Create models include the ItemVersion?  I would then add fields from the ItemVersion to the form and when the Create button is clicked, the form values are inserted into the Item table table and the ItemVersion table.

My Get and Post handlers:

```
 public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }


[BindProperty]
public Item Item { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Item.Add(Item);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Comment: The `Item` Entity has a property of `ItemDetailId` , and also has a navigation property `ItemDetail` at the same time . What make me confused is ... why the type of `ItemDetail`  is `ICollection<ItemDetail>` ? It seems that there will be only one `ItemDetail` .

Comment: I just used ItemDetail to simplify my actual project.  Maybe ItemVersion would be more descriptive.  There can be one to many ItemVersions.  I've updated my post. As far as the ItemDetailId property that was my mistake.  It shouldn't be there. I've updated that too.

Comment: You want to add multi ItemVersion into Item, right?

Comment: No. Just one item version at a time. So when initially creating an item, there must be a version associated with it.  And then when I'm editing an item, I should have the option to add another version.